# How to get one field in oledb c# program based on the value of textbox?

Tags: c#

I get Oledb exception

```
private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\cus1.mdb");


    ada = new OleDbDataAdapter("select ubal from cus1 where uname="+this.label3.Text,con);
    ds = new DataSet();

    //OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT ubal FROM cus1 WHERE uname=@uname");

    //ocb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(ada);
    //textBox2.Text = label3.Text;


    ada.Fill(ds,"cus1");
    textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "cus1.ubal");
    bm = this.BindingContext[ds.Tables[0]];


    // cmd.CommandText ="SELECT treatment FROM appointment WHERE patientid=@patientID";


}
```

how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing single quotes around your text.  But to avoid a whole boat load of problems regarding your sql queries, including [sql injection](http://xkcd.com/327/), *always* use parameters:

```
ada = new OleDbDataAdapter("select ubal from cus1 where uname=?", con);
ada.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", this.label3.Text);
```